# execute .Bat file under remote user

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, dfs

We have a windows service running under an AD Account. This account is a non personnel account and has limited access (can not log in locally, etc.)

This service tries to access a DFS share (the account has modify privileges on the share).

The share has .bat file with some commands. To test it, i just replaced all the commands with a simple copy command.

```
PING 127.0.0.1 -n 15 || PING ::1 -n 15
copy "\\share\folder\hell.txt" "\\share\folder\hell2.txt"
```

However the .bat file never gets executed. When i look at the `procmon` dump, i see that `cmd.exe` is called but it never completes and eventually the service crashes.

if i run

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\account "\\share\folder\test.bat"
```

then .bat file executes and i see the file copied.

Any suggestions on what the issue might be are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> This account is a non personnel account and has limited access (**can
>   not log in locally**, etc.)

Please remove the `logon to` restriction and test again, as it need a logon to access the share `\\share\folder`

You can confirm that from your security's log too.